# How to use Entity with property of type byte to render checkbox in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on a `ASP.NET MVC 4` project. I use `Entity Framework 5` and `Code First` workflow. Here is part of my entity:

```
public class News
{
    //Other properties...
    public byte IsShortNews { get; set; }

}
```

When I edit an existing news I want to render the checkbox. The compiler complains about not being able to parse `byte` to `bool` so I tried this :

```
<li>
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => (m.IsShortNews == 1? true : false))
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsShortNews, new { @class = "checkbox" })
</li>
```

And I get this error :

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Which I'm not sure what exactly wants to tell me but it seems that I won't solve my problem so easily.

Searching the web I found this solution:

```
   public byte IsShortNews {get;set;}
   [NotMapped]
   public bool IsShortNewsBool 
   {
       get { return IsShortNews > 0; }
       set { IsShortNews = value ? 1 : 0; }
   }
```

but I have little experience before with `NotMapped` properties and I don't know if it was specifically for that application but we decided that it's better to get rid of them from the project so I decided to look for another solution.

In the view where I create news I use ViewModel where `IsShortNews` is declared as bool and then in my controller I just `news.IsShortNews = model.IsShortNews? (byte)1 : (byte)0;` but I'm not sure if using a viewmodel here is a good choice. Since it's an existing record in the database and I have to use the entity to get it :`News model = unitOfWork.NewsRepository.GetById(Id);` and then have to create another object with my viewmodel type - `NewsModel vModel = new NewsModel();` then copy the values from the one object to the other in order to pass a model to the view and... it seems like a lot of work for something like this.

Comment: Why are you using a `byte` instead of a `bool` if your values are 1 or 0? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For boolean values, you need to make your database columm type a `bit` and your class property a `bool` and you won't need to do any extra work to display a checkbox.

```
public class News
{
    //Other properties...
    public bool IsShortNews { get; set; }
}
```

HTML

```
<li>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsShortNews)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsShortNews, new { @class = "checkbox" })
</li>
```

Comment: Sorry to respond so late, I thought nobody gonna pay attention on friday. It's actually `Code First` so my database is autogenerated based on my entities. IS it enough just to declare `IsShortNews` as bool in my entity for `EF` to do all the job of creating the table with the correct types?

Comment: @Leron I guess you already found out since you accepted this answer, but yes you only need to declare the property as bool and EF will take care of the rest in a code first scenario.